# How to expose the Redis+Sentinel to outside in KiND cluster

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I am new to Kubernetes. I am using [Given Link](https://github.com/marcel-dempers/docker-development-youtube-series/tree/master/storage/redis/kubernetes) to create 3 node Redis cluster(1 master and 2 slaves) and 3 node sentinel. It is easy to get started but I am confused with the 2 following things

1. I am running it KiND cluster so I need to know how can I access the Redis cluster from local. I think I need to create a service and expose it but I am not sure how.
2. I am not sure if from outside, I access the master or the sentinel to access the Redis cluster.
3. If I access either of master or sentinel, what would happen to the connection, if the given pod crashes and restarts.

I am new to k8s but I hope the question wasn't completely stupid. Also there is a supplement video for this can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmCn7k0PlV4)

Answer (score 0):

You can expose Redis master outside the cluster using the master.service.type parameter (set it to NodePort or LoadBalancer types). That said, it's very likely that Redis Sentinel is not returning the external IP/port or the Redis master node but the internal ones instead

You may use redisinsight as web based UI to monitor and trace Redis cluster
https://gist.github.com/chrisedrego/9a428ed94126445af4770a749bf797e5

Comment: Thanks for your comment! However being a newbie in k8s, it is not very clear to me. Can you please elaborate a bit may be with the given manifests?